# Enumerating Google spreadsheets?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-sheets-api

I'm fiddling with Google Sheets AP v4, starting with [this introduction](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet). The API seems pretty clear but I can't figure out how to enumerate existing spreadsheets. Is that not a supported feature for some reason or am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by enumerate existing spreadsheets? can you give a little more information on what you are trying to achieve and what you have already tried?

Comment: By enumerating I mean get a list of all existing spreadsheets. What tutorials and examples I've seen so far it's possible to open existing and create new ones but I have seen no option to check which ones exist.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the list of sheet names by using this code:

```
var spreadsheets = service.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadSheetId).Execute();

var titles = spreadsheets.Sheets.Select(s => s.Properties.Title).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sheets get returns a sheet [resource](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet) which contains a list of sheets within a sheet.

So it's just a matter of getting the sheet you are interested in and you will have a list of the sheets it contains

Comment: I might have misunderstood the model then. I interpret "spreadsheet" as a document which contains "sheets" (tabs). What I need to enumerate are the documents ("spreadsheets"). From what I've seen of the API so far I'm required to know the actual ID of the document/spreadsheet I need before I can open it as a resource, which is useless for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you want a list of all Spreadsheets on your google drive account your going to have to Go though the google drive API.   Then use the Google sheets API to list the sheets (tabs) with in each sheet.   TOP tip a file id (google drive) is a spreadsheet id (sheets API).